# how to use hook_views_api to load the views in a module in drupal

Tags: drupal

my module.views.inc and .module file are located in the same folder

I want to use hook_views_api() to call the .views.inc file
The following code does not work

  `function module_name_views_api(){
    return array(
    'api' => 2,
    'path' => array('module','module_name'),
  );
}`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If yourmodule.views.inc and yourmodule.module are in the same folder, I don't think you need the path part. The following example works in one of my modules:

```
function mymodule_views_api() {
  return array('api' => 2.0);
}
```

Comment: You don't *have to* use it, but in my opinion, you *should* use it to separate Views data - as it produces a nicer and clear structure for your modules. For example, you could place files that are related to Views module in a directory called "views" like in uc_product.module (so use it like this: ... `'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') .'/views',` ...).

Answer (score 7):

Only use path if you want to store views code in a different directory within the module. Example below will load any views code from "mymodule/includes/views". It's a good way of keeping your module directory clean.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function mymodule_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 2.0,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/includes/views',
  );
}
```

Comment: +1: oops, just wrote a comment with similar content under the other answer (saw your answer subsequently). I totally agree with you, Views data should be separated.